# Accessing Firebase data in a node with JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have an object being returned from Firebase that looks like this:

`{key: {name: "test", email: "test", id: "test"}}`

How can I get the id out of this object?

If I do `returnItem` I get that object, so I tried to do `returnItem[0]` but it's not an array, and I've tried `(Object.keys(tempSnap)` but that just gives me the key not the object inside it.

This is my current code:

```
export function sendInvitation(email) {
    firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        let tempSnap = snapshot.val();
        if(tempSnap != null) {
            console.log(tempSnap);
        }
    });
    return dispatch => firebaseRef.database().ref(`${userID}/invites`).push("This is a test Message!"); 
}
```

This is what it outputs:

[image: Returned Value]

Help would be awesome :D

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49131993/edit) your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Hope this helps clear up the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know `id` and it's a literal, then it's a matter of `returnItem.id`.

If you already know `id` and it's a variable, then it's `returnItem[id]`.

If you don't know the keys and want to print all keys and their values, it's:

```
Object.keys(returnItem).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, returnItem[key]);
});
```

**Update**

Your new code shows the problem. When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. Your callback needs to handle the fact that it gets a list by looping over the results with `snapshot.forEach()`:

```
firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    let tempSnap = child.val();
    console.log(tempSnap);
  });
});
```

Comment: so the key is auto-generated and I don't know it. I've tried what you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. returnedItem[id] throws an error saying it doesn't know what id is (I'm trying to get it's value so I don't know it)

Comment: That error sounds like id` is not a literal. Since you don't know its value, you may have to loop as in the last snippet I gave. But it's hard to help better with the limited information you gave in your question. For better help: make sure you post the JSON that you're listening to (as text, no screenshots), the way you attach a listener from your code, and the actual code inside the listener. All of these may affect what you need to do to get the value.

Comment: I updated the question with more info, maybe that'll help

Comment: Nailed it! That's exactly what I needed, thank you. So what exactly am I looking over here? sorry I'm trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
firebaseRef.database().ref().child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    let keys=child.key;
    let ids=child.val().id;
      )};
   )};
```

you have:

```
 users
  keyid
   email:email
   name:yourname
   id: test
```

Comment: So that just returns the key of the object. I need the id inside of it

Comment: check now @EladKarni